# make stripe to not work on testing credit card number

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I just made a simple checkout with stripe and I tested it with test credit card number:

`424242424242`

and it worked but when I will switch to development mode I need stripe to not consider every test credit card number as valid, so do I need to include some additional code or what do I need to do?

Comment: I think you meant when you switch to production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing with Stripe is very simple.

https://stripe.com/docs/testing

And no, if you switch to *production* Stripe will work just fine. And **it will not** consider an invalid credit card as valid.

Comment: oh thank you, stripe is really fun but i could not find switching option in dashboard